# Pass react state to paypal button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

How can I pass React Component State to function below:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/#step-1-add-payment-buttons

```
  componentDidMount() {
window.paypal
      .Buttons({
        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
              {
                amount: {
                  value: "0.01",
                },
              },
            ],
          });
        },
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                alert("Transaction completed by " + details.payer.name.given_name);
              });
            },
          })
          .render("#paypal-button-container");
}
```

I would like to do this:

```
     return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
        alert("Transaction completed by " + details.payer.name.given_name);
        this.callMyFunction() //<-------------------------
      });
```

I already tried to use .bind(this)

And I event tried to detect when the browser saw an alert

No luck with either attempt.

Comment: try writing the `then` callback as an arrow function: `return actions.order.capture().then((details) => {...})`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @RobinZigmond

Looks like the paypal function rewrites the "this" object
So I created a local variable `var that = this`
Now I have access to any react function I want

```
componentDidMount() {
var that = this
window.paypal
      .Buttons({
        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
              {
                amount: {
                  value: "0.01",
                },
              },
            ],
          });
        },
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then((details)=> {
          console.log(this)
          console.log(that)
                    alert("Transaction completed by " + details.payer.name.given_name);
                  });
                },
              })
              .render("#paypal-button-container");
    }
```